# Improve performance on a st_dwithin query (in PostGIS)

Tags: postgis, st-dwithin

At the momenent I am working on a query, as described in an [earlier question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173411/update-table-based-on-closest-point-between-its-geometrypoint-and-another-tabl). I have the two tables

1. testme (tracked GPS-profile with Point Geometry) and
2. roads (geometry roads shapefile)

Besides the distance of each tracked point (row) in table pt in want to find the closest point using a combination of ST_Distance and ST_DWithin.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS raw_2015_processed;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
CREATE TABLE raw_2015_processed AS
SELECT pt.id, 
    pt."DeliveryID",
    pt."VehicleID",
    pt."TrackID",
    pt."Longitude",
    pt."Latitude",
    pt."Altitude",
    pt."Heading",
    pt."Speed",
    pt."Satelites",
    pt."HDOP",
    pt."VDOP",
    pt."Xfcd",
    pt.ts,
    pt.received,
    pt.the_geom,
(SELECT ST_ClosestPoint(line.geom,pt.the_geom) AS closest_geom
    FROM roads AS line 
    WHERE ST_DWithin(line.geom,pt.the_geom, 0.5) LIMIT 1),
(SELECT ST_Distance(line.geom,pt.the_geom) AS distance
    FROM roads AS line
    ORDER BY pt.the_geom <#> line.geom LIMIT 1),
(SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ClosestPoint(line.geom, pt.the_geom)) AS closest_coordinates
    FROM roads AS line
    ORDER BY pt.the_geom <#> line.geom LIMIT 1)
FROM raw_2015 AS pt
ORDER by pt.id;`
```

Working with a reduced file 'Testme' of 144 rows EXPLAIN ANALYZE returns following Query Plan:

```
"Sort  (cost=84207.04..84207.40 rows=144 width=131) (actual time=11797.677..11797.685 rows=144 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: pt.id"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 54kB"
"  ->  Seq Scan on testme pt  (cost=0.00..84201.87 rows=144 width=131) (actual time=82.458..11797.268 rows=144 loops=1)"
"        SubPlan 1"
"          ->  Limit  (cost=9.46..578.16 rows=1 width=155) (actual time=81.508..81.508 rows=1 loops=144)"
"                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on roads line  (cost=9.46..578.16 rows=1 width=155) (actual time=81.388..81.388 rows=1 loops=144)"
"                      Recheck Cond: (geom && st_expand(pt.the_geom, 0.5::double precision))"
"                      Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 0"
"                      Filter: ((pt.the_geom && st_expand(geom, 0.5::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(geom, pt.the_geom, 0.5::double precision))"
"                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on geom_index_roads  (cost=0.00..9.46 rows=139 width=0) (actual time=79.722..79.722 rows=450402 loops=144)"
"                            Index Cond: (geom && st_expand(pt.the_geom, 0.5::double precision))"
"        SubPlan 2"
```

However, when I run the query for a larger dataset with more data points (< 5 Million points) , it gets very slow (i.e. several hours / days). Do you guys see a way to increase the speed of the query? Is there an an alternative option to st_dwithin or a different query structure which can proof to be helpful?

Comment: what projection/SRID  are your tables in ?

Comment: Geometries in table "testme" is geometry(Point,4326) and in table "roads" it is geometry(LineString,4326)

Comment: so you are asking for the nearest road with .5 degrees of the point (which is quite a long way)

Comment: Could you post the explain from the query on the smaller dataset? I have had similar issues with large datasets where the query optimizer uses a different plan. Also, you should consider accepting the previous answer, as it answers the question as stated :-)

Comment: I have a feeling that the roads table is not vacuumed and/or a spatial index is not build on it

Comment: and for better viewing : http://explain.depesz.com/s/nHS

Comment: If you are using the <#> operator with limit 1, then you should not need to use ST_DWithin, as it will automatically find the nearest point, no matter how far/close. There are issues around the <#>, one of which is that one of the geometries should be a constant. I am not sure if this has been resolved in recent version of Postgis.

Answer (score 5):

Did you create spatial indexes for both tables and CLUSTER on those? In my experience this really speeds up these kinds of queries and the CLUSTER part is often neglected by users and tutorials, etc.

```
CREATE INDEX line_2010_index ON line USING GIST (geom); 
CLUSTER line USING line_index;

CREATE INDEX raw_2015_index ON raw_2015 USING GIST (the_geom); 
CLUSTER raw_2015 USING raw_2015_index;
```