# Improve Performance of ST_DWithin - H2GIS

Tags: sql, spatial-query, st-dwithin, h2gis

I have a table seg_point, that I create like this:

```
CREATE TABLE seg_point (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, segmentid TEXT, geom GEOMETRY);
```

And I'm trying to improve the performance of this query that looks for the nearest match within 5 km (5000 m):

```
SELECT SEGMENTID, ST_AsText(geom) AS geom, ST_Distance(ST_Transform(seg_point.geom, 3857), ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || ? || ' ' || ? || ')', 4326), 3857)) AS DISTANCE 
FROM seg_point 
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(seg_point.geom, 3857), ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || ? || ' ' || ? || ')', 4326), 3857), 1000) 
ORDER BY DISTANCE 
limit 1
```

I saw this post and tried creating a spatial index:

[Improve performance on a st_dwithin query (in PostGIS)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174712/improve-performance-on-a-st-dwithin-query-in-postgis)

I can create the index, but it doesn't seem that h2gis supports CLUSTER.

Any other suggestions for improving the query?

Comment: Calculating distances based on Web Mercator is a major flaw in your plan. Even if you manage to get fast results, they'll still be unreliable.

Comment: @Vince Thanks for the response. The goal of the query is to map match a given lat/lon to the closest point. All points lie within North America (the continental US and lower region of Canada). Is there a different projection you'd recommend? I'm not a GIS expert, but based on my research I was wondering if [Albers Equal Conic](https://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/usa-contiguous-albers-equal-area-conic/html/) would be better?

Comment: If this were PostGIS, I'd use transform to 4326 and a cast to `geography`, the a geodetic `ST_DWithin`. Deprojecting is less expensive than reprojecting, especially when datum transformation is required.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I had read somewhere that points should be stored in 4326, so that's how I've been storing them. Unfortunately, I don't think H2GIS has the geography type. I'll have to consider if it's worth the effort to switch to PostGIS for our project.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up switching over to using a PostGIS database instead of H2GIS and am using the Geography type with clustered indices and am getting much faster (and I think accurate) results.